# Why are integer literals with leading zeroes interpreted strangely?

Tags: java

This prints 83

```
System.out.println(0123)
```

However this prints 123

```
System.out.println(123)
```

Why does it work that way?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

A leading zero denotes that the literal is expressed using [octal (a base-8 number)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal).

0123 can be converted by doing `(1 * 8 * 8) + (2 * 8) + (3)`, which equals 83 in decimal.
For some reason, octal floats are not available.

Just don't use the leading zero if you don't intend the literal to be expressed in octal.

There is also a `0x` prefix which denotes that the literal is expressed in hexadecimal (base 16).

Answer (score 16):

Because integer literals starting with `0` are treated as octal numbers.

See section 3.10.1 of the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1)

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
public static String leftPad(int n, int padding) {
    return String.format("%0" + padding + "d", n);
}
leftPad(5, 3); // return "005"
leftPad(15, 5); // return "00015"
leftPad(224, 3); // return "224"
leftPad(0, 4); // return "0000"
```

Answer (score 4):

first one printed as 83 because java takes 0123 as octal number and it prints decimal equivalent of that number.

Answer (score 4):

The octal (leading 0) and hexadecimal (leading 0x) were inherited from C.
For comparison, try

```
System.out.println(0x123);
```

Answer (score 2):

In Java integer literals with a leading zero are octal integers (base 8).

```
(1 * 8^2) + (2 * 8^1) + (3 * 8^0) = 83
```

So do not use any number leading with 0 if you don't want to treat it as an octal number.

Answer (score 1):

```
0123 -> 83
1010L -> 1010  
0101L -> 65
```

The numbers `1010L` and `0101L` are not in binary representation (just to avoid the confusion).
These numbers are in decimal representation.

Even as per the Regex patterns in [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html),

> \0n is the character with octal value 0n (0 <= n <= 7) 
>   \xhh is the character with hexadecimal value 0xhh

Thus, your number `0101` be it in `Integer` or `Long` format is treated as an Octal representation of a number.

```
123 => 1 * 8^2 + 2 * 8^1 + 1 * 8^0 = 83
0101 => 1 * 8^2 + 0 * 8^1 + 1 * 8^0 = 64 + 0 + 1 = 65
```

Answer (score 0):

`printf` will do it: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/sprintf/

```
public class X
{
    public static void main(final String[] argv)
    {
        System.out.printf("%04d", 123);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

You could also make it `"%0" + size + "%d"` if you wanted to vary the length... though if the lengths were common I'd probably make constants like `"%04d"`, `"%012d"`, etc...