# recursive function to add digits in python fails when leading digit is zero

Tags: python, recursion

I'm trying to create a recursive function that adds all the digits in a number. Here's what I've come up with:

```
def sumOfDigits(num):
    num=str(num)
    if len(num)==0:
        return 0
    elif len(num)==1:
        return int(num)
    elif len(num)>1:
        return int(num[0]) + int(num[-1]) + int(sumOfDigits(num[1:-1]))
```

this seems to work for almost any number:

```
sumOfDigits(999999999)
>>>81
sumOfDigits(1234)
>>>10
sumOfDigits(111)
>>>3
sumOfDigits(1)
>>>1
sumOfDigits(0)
>>>0
```

strange things happen though if the number begins with '0'

```
sumOfDigits(012)
>>>1
sumOfDigits(0123)
>>>11
sumOfDigits(00010)
>>>8
```

what am I missing here??

Comment: This is purely for curiosity sake?

Comment: nope. trying to solve this issue.

Comment: `sum(map(int, str(digits)))` then ? (but you'd still have the same issue that's been addressed) - just absolutely no need to use recursion for this

Comment: apparently i figured out about the 'octal' numbers the hard way. sorry to take everyones time. I am trying to understand recursion better through this function, otherwise I would use what you suggest Jon. Thanks

Comment: we all had to pick it up from somewhere - don't worry about it :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**In Python 2, integer literals that start with zero are [octal](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#integer-and-long-integer-literals)**.

To take your examples:

```
In [46]: 012
Out[46]: 10

In [47]: 0123
Out[47]: 83

In [48]: 0010
Out[48]: 8
```

Since your function works in base ten, it is doing its job correctly. :)

As an aside, you need neither string manipulation nor recursion for this problem. Since others have already suggested non-recursive solutions, here is a recursive one that doesn't use string manipulation:

```py
def sumOfDigits(n):
   return 0 if n == 0 else sumOfDigits(n // 10) + n % 10
```

Comment: Note that in Python 3 the OP cannot make this mistake as octal literals are now expressed `0o12` not `012`.

Comment: didn't know about 'octal' integer literals. Thanks! will look into it.

Comment: Which is a very sensible change and really how it should have been to begin with.

Comment: @jdotjdot one could also argue that `print` should never have been a statement, and that blah blah blah.... :)

Comment: I actually don't have a problem with `print` as a statement.  The only things I really have problems with are where the syntax directly opposes what you think it should do, and does so silently--octals being a great example.  `print` just prints, even if it's a statement instead of a function.  As this OP is seeing, that extra `0` in front of the number makes everything go wrong, and there's no obvious way to figure out way, since when `013` evaluates to `11`, it's still an `int`, and even `oct(013)` returns a `str`!

Answer (score 2):

To be honest, there's an easier way to do this whole thing.

```
sum(map(int, str(num)))
```

Note that this doesn't take care of the octal string issue wisely pointed out above.

Answer (score 0):

Numbers stats with `0` are treated as octal number .

Octal Value for `00010` is 8 .

For more refer the post [binary numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4485550/binary-numbers) .

Python numbers starts with `0` will not work . For octal number you have to specify `Oo` to convert it as octal number.