# error during grouping files based on the date field

Tags: java, string, io

I have a large file which has 10,000 rows and each row has a date appended at the end. All the fields in a row are tab separated. There are 10 dates available and those 10 dates have randomly been assigned to all the 10,000 rows. I am now writing a java code to write all those rows with the same date into a separate file where each file has the corresponding rows with that date.

I am trying to do it using string manipulations, but when I am trying to sort the rows based on date, I am getting an error while mentioning the date and the error says the ***literal is out of range***. Here is the code that I used. Please have a look at it let me know if this is the right approach, if not, kindly suggest a better approach. I tried changing the datatype to Long, but still the same error. The row in the file looks something like this:
Each field is tab separated and the fields are:

business id, category, city, biz.name, longitude, state, latitude, type, date

**

> qarobAbxGSHI7ygf1f7a_Q    ["Sandwiches","Restaurants"]    Gilbert     Jersey
>   Mike's Subs      -111.8120071 AZ  3.5 33.3788385  business    06012010

**
The code is:

```
    File f=new File(fn);
    if(f.exists() && f.length()>0)
    {
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fn));
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("FilteredDate.txt"));

        String s=null;
        while((s=br.readLine())!=null){
            String[] st=s.split("\t");

            if(Integer.parseInt(st[13])==06012010){
```

Thanks a lot for your time..

Comment: 06012010 - this number starts with "0" - it is octal number in Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
List<String> sampleList = new ArrayList<String>();
        sampleList.add("06012012");
        sampleList.add("06012013");
        sampleList.add("06012014");
        sampleList.add("06012015");
```

//

//

```
    String[] sampleArray = s.split(" ");
                if (sampleArray != null)
                {
                    String sample = sampleArray[sampleArray.length - 1];

                    if (sampleList.contains(sample))
                    {
                        stringBuilder.append(sample + "\n");
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

i suggest not to use split, but rather use

```
String str = s.subtring(s.lastIndexOf('\t'));
```

in any case, you try to take `st[13]` when i see you only have 9 columns. might be you just need `st[8]`

one last thing, look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7218760/why-is-08-not-a-valid-integer-literal-in-java) post to learn what 06012010 really means