# Parameter passed from Java is automatically converted to Octal equivalent in JSP Page

Tags: java, jsp

When a variable is passed from java layer to JSP, if the string starts with 0(Zero), it is automatically converts it to Octal otherwise it is working fine.

Inside the Java code I am sending one distID

```
response.sendRedirect("ExpTool.jsp?test=1&&distID="+distID);
```

And inside the JSP code I am receiving the distID as

```
String distID=(String)request.getParameter("distID");
```

Its working fine except the scenario when distID is like '004352' i.e., when it starts with '0(zero)'. Whenever it starts with '0', it is automatically converted into its Octal Equivalent.
I need solution for the scenario when distID starts with '0'.

Comment: And what is the question? And where does JavaScript enter the question? Please visit the [help] to see how and what to ask here. If your question is JavaScript related, you need to use radix 10 - `parseInt("09",10)` to get integers - same for 08

Comment: If the value is a number, why are you passing it from Java as a String?

Comment: You have not provided a single line of code that is relevant to your question. Please amend your question with code snippet so that we can help you better.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I work around JavaScript's parseInt octal behavior?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/850341/how-do-i-work-around-javascripts-parseint-octal-behavior)

Comment: yea javascript is not there, i got confused. Its in normal JSP page, can you help on that? And sorry if my question is not clear, I want that the variable that I am passing through java layer should not be converted to Octal even if it is starting from 0(zero).

Comment: Please post your code. It's java, rather than javascript, correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is 08 not a valid integer literal in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7218760/why-is-08-not-a-valid-integer-literal-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Evidently
- you want a number
- for some reason there are preceding zeroes

Call `somepage.jsp?notsixteen=020`. As a String request parameter in java is no problem, probably the problem if for `${...}`:

Expression Language:

```
${2 + Integer.parseInt(param.notsixteen, 10)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please verify this:

```
request.getParameter("distID");
                      ^^^^^^
```

it should be "dist" not the "distID" as you have written. As your request parameter name is "dist";

Comment: Actually its a copy paste mistake... in code its fine.

Comment: You can use  Integer.toOctalString(Integer.parseInt(s)) to convert integer back to octal or original representation.