# unable to rename file with dynamic paths in jmeter using beanshell

Tags: java, string, jmeter, beanshell

I am trying to rename a file using beanshell sampler in jmeter

I have simple code where I am trying to assign the path (dynamically change filename and append to the path) to a file func.

```
String filename=  "\"C:\\Users\\Thaneer_M\\Downloads\\apache-jmeter-2.13_save\\JmeterRecordings\\PerfIssues\\All Savers Insurance Company_PerformanceCheck"+024+".xlsx\"";
File file = new File(${filename});

File file2 = new File("C:\\Users\\Thaneer_M\\Downloads\\apache-jmeter-2.13_save\\JmeterRecordings\\PerfIssues\\All Savers Insurance Company_PerformanceCheck025.xlsx");

boolean success = file.renameTo(file2);
if (!success) {
log.info "file renamed successfully"
}
```

I am able to successfully renamed the file if I use a static filepath like

```
File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Thaneer_M\\Downloads\\apache-jmeter-2.13_save\\JmeterRecordings\\PerfIssues\\All Savers Insurance Company_PerformanceCheck025.xlsx");
File file2 = new File("C:\\Users\\Thaneer_M\\Downloads\\apache-jmeter-2.13_save\\JmeterRecordings\\PerfIssues\\All Savers Insurance Company_PerformanceCheck026.xlsx");
 boolean success = file.renameTo(file2);
if (!success) {    log.info "file renamed successfully"    }
```

error:

```
inline evaluation of: ``String filename=  ("C:\Users\Thaneer_M\Downloads\apache-jmeter-2.13_save\JmeterR . . . '' Token Parsing Error: Lexical error at line 1, column 24.  Encountered: "U" (85), after : "\"C:\\"
```

the files name change dynamically and I want to be able to create filepath string dynamically by appending integer to the file name.

Can some one please advise.

thank you

Comment: I'd try using \\\\ instead of \\

Comment: @MarianP

the path of the file is C:\Users\Thaneer_M\Downloads\apache-jmeter-2.13_save\JmeterRecordings\PerfIssues\All Savers Insurance Company_PerformanceCheck290.xlsx actually 

so I am escaping \ by using \\ 
is it right ?

Comment: first \\ escapes to a java string containing \, bean shell evaluates again so it might need another escaping. or just use /

Comment: using just / did not work ..:(

Answer (score 2):

Few suggestions:

1. Remove starting and ending `\"`, they're not required
2. Make sure you have double slashes everywhere. Alternative cross-platform option will be replacing slashes with [File.separator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#separator) like:

   ```
   "Users" + File.separator + "Thaneer_M" + File.separator + "..."
   ```
3. Beanshell treats `024` is an [Octal integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7218760/why-is-08-not-a-valid-integer-literal-in-java), make sure you use it correctly and know what you're doing. If you need exactly "024" value it's better to pass it as a string

Some debugging options:

- `log.info("something")` will print the line to *jmeter.log* file. This way you can see variable values
- Placing `debug();` line at the very beginning of your Beanshell script will trigger debug output to stdout
- surrounding your code with try/catch and printing exception stacktrace to jmeter.log provides more information on Beanshell errors, like:

  ```
  try {
      //your code here
  }
  catch (Throwable e) {
      log.error("Error in Beanshell", e);
  }
  ```

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for more detailed information on Beanshell scripting in JMeter.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened for me. To solve the problem I performed the following thing in Beanshell code:

1. Open the source file.
2. Copy the contents to a temp file
3. Delete the source file using file.delete()
4. Create a new file with the same name as the source file.
5. Copy contents of temp file in this new file.
6. Delete temp file.

I know this is not the best approach but this worked in jmeter 3.0.

Thanks,
Sumit Pal.