# Trying to print a casted array of ints into chars,but I get message "integer number too large"

Tags: java, arrays, integer

Hello guys I just started learning java and I'm got my name in ascii numbers in a int array and i'm trying to loop thru it while casting each int ascii to a char

```
package program1;

/**
 *
 * @author Gust-X
 */
public class Program1 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] firstName;
        firstName = new int[6];

        firstName[0] = 071;
        firstName[1] = 117;
        firstName[2] = 115;
        firstName[3] = 116;
        firstName[4] = 097;
        firstName[5] = 118;


        for(int x = 0; x < 6; ++x ){
            System.out.print((char)firstName[x]);
        }
        // TODO code application logic here
    }

}
```

I get a red line under `firstName[4] = 097;` saying integer number too large 097

Comment: `097` is not a valid octal number.

Comment: A better duplicate: [Why is 08 not a valid integer literal in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7218760/why-is-08-not-a-valid-integer-literal-in-java).