# What does an integer that has zero in front of it mean and how can I print it?

Tags: java, int, output, zero, println

```
class test{
  public static void main(String args[]){
     int a = 011;
     System.out.println(a);
  }
}
```

Why I am getting `9` as output instead of `011`?

How can I get `011` as output?

Comment: `String.format("%02d", a)`

Comment: 011 is a literal in base 8, so in base 10 you get 9=(8^1+8^0). see http://stackoverflow.com/a/7218803/5166645 for more details

Comment: numbers that start with 0 are called hex numbers.

Comment: @SmashCode not exactly. Numbers written with a leading "0" in Java are called **octal** and are base 8 (octa- is the Greek prefix for 8). Numbers written with a leading "0x" are called **hexadecimal** (hex for short) and are base 16 (hexa- is the Greek prefix for 6 and deci- is the Latin prefix for 10). Regular numbers are called **decimal** because they are base 10.

Octal and hexadecimal are useful because they are much easier to convert to binary than decimal.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [JLS 3.10.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html) describes 4 ways to define integers.

> An integer literal may be expressed in **decimal** (base 10), **hexadecimal** (base 16), **octal** (base 8), or **binary** (base 2).
>
> An octal numeral consists of **a digit 0 followed by one or more of the digits 0 through 7** ...
>
> A decimal numeral is either the single digit 0, representing the integer zero, or consists of an digit from 1 to 9 optionally followed by one or more digits from 0 to 9 ...

In summary if your integer literal (i.e. `011`) starts with a 0, then java will assume it's an [octal notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal#Octal_to_decimal_conversion).

[image: octal conversion example]

## Solutions:

If you want your integer to hold the value 11, then don't be fancy, just assign 11. After all, the notation doesn't change anything to the value. I mean, from a mathematical point of view 11 = 011 = 11,0.

```
int a = 11;
```

The formatting only matters when you print it (or when you convert your `int` to a `String`).

```
String with3digits = String.format("%03d", a);
System.out.println(with3digits);
```

The formatter `"%03d"` is used to add leading zeroes.

[image: formatter]

Alternatively, you could do it in 1 line, using the `printf` method.

```
System.out.printf("%03d", a);
```

Answer (score 2):

A numeric literal that starts with 0 is parsed as an octal number (i.e. radix 8). 011 is 9 in octal.

Answer (score 1):

The `011` is being interpreted as an octal number. This means it's in base 8. See also [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7218760/why-is-08-not-a-valid-integer-literal-in-java). From the accepted answer by Stuart Cook:

> In Java and several other languages, an integer literal beginning with 0 is interpreted as an octal (base 8) quantity.

Digits in Base 10:
100s, 10s, 1s

Digits in Base 8:
64s, 8s, 1s

So the `011` is interpreted as 8+1=9