# Whats difference between this two: BigInteger.valueOf(10000) and BigInteger.valueOf(0010000)?

Tags: java, numeric, biginteger

I was working with one problem and came across this. What happen is:

when we use this:
`BigInteger.valueOf(10000)` it gives value of `10000`

But

when we use this `BigInteger.valueOf(0010000)` it gives value of `4096`

Whats the difference between the two?

Comment: See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is 08 not a valid integer literal in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7218760/why-is-08-not-a-valid-integer-literal-in-java)

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt : this example will help user in understanding of possible scenario. as it happen with me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

0010000 is an octal literal. This has nothing to do with `BigInteger` - it's just Java integer literals ([JLS 3.10.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1)):

```
System.out.println(10000);   // 10000
System.out.println(0010000); // 4096
```

From the JLS:

> A decimal numeral is either the single ASCII digit 0, representing the integer zero, or consists of an ASCII digit from 1 to 9 optionally followed by one or more ASCII digits from 0 to 9 interspersed with underscores, representing a positive integer.
>
> ...
>
> An octal numeral consists of an ASCII digit 0 followed by one or more of the ASCII digits 0 through 7 interspersed with underscores, and can represent a positive, zero, or negative integer.

Answer (score 3):

this is taking decimal literal as parameter

```
BigInteger.valueOf(10000)
```

and this is taking an octal literal as parameter

`BigInteger.valueOf(0010000)` [because begins with 0](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-OctalIntegerLiteral)

so you are technically passing 2 different numbers

1. 10000

and

2. 4096

Answer (score 2):

The second one is integer in octal system, the first in decimal, that is the reason of the difference