# JAVA - Storing phone number in which data type?

Tags: java, eclipse, phone-number

I am using Eclipse in java and it is giving me this error when i try to store a cell phone number in different data type.

The literal 03126193172 of type int is out of range

```
    int n=03126193172;
    long n=03126193172;
    long m=03126193172L;
```

Comment: What language? Your title also has a different question than what your text implies. Please edit it to be clear in what you are asking. Also note that leading zeroes may change things in certain languages.

Comment: Use a String. How would you store +33 (0)6 02 00 00 01 in a number? Even just 03126193172 can't be stored. Printing it would not diaplay the leading 0.

Comment: I can use string i know but my question is to gather knowledge why int and long data types can't store that number? I think this number is not out of their range.

Comment: Then you should mention it in your question and make the question more clear. Have a clear problem description and your finding.

Comment: @SilentCoder, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7218760/why-is-08-not-a-valid-integer-literal-in-java

Comment: totally misleading question :/