# Java compiler shows error that “integer is too large”

Tags: java

when I add integer number it's show me "integer too large" even if I make it double howto solve this

```
public class Three {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i = 05955555;
}
```

Comment: Remove leading 0. It sets literal in octal base so only 0-7 digits are accepted.

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7218760/why-is-08-not-a-valid-integer-literal-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
int i = 5955555;
```

In Java, an integer number starting with `0` is interpreted as being in octal base - and in that base, you can't have the digit `9`.