# JAVA Code snippet: Explanation of octal / radix 8 numbers

Tags: java

Need Explanation of this Code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 
        int a=010; 
        int b=07; 
        System.out.println(a); 
        System.out.println(b); 
}
```

**OutPut** :

8

7

Comment: Those are octal numbers

Comment: It's just `int` in radix 8

Comment: I need explanation of how 8 is calculated ?

Comment: Have a look on this question: [Why is 08 not a valid integer literal in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7218760/why-is-08-not-a-valid-integer-literal-in-java)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal Can you clarify what you are having trouble with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An int prepended with `0`in Java represents an *Octal*, which means you count to 7, then represent the (decimal) value of 8 as 10, and continue form there.

As an example / for comparison:

```
Decimal       Octal
8             10
9             11
10            12
11            13
16            20
17            21
24            30
25            31
64            100
65            101
etc...
```