# Math.min doesn't like numbers starting with 0. (0700)

Tags: java, math, min

I've been getting problems with the Math.min more so when I try to do

```
System.out.println(Math.min(0700,1400));
```

it returns 448 instead of 0700 the minimum value. I know it works when the 0 isn't there, but due to user input I kinda need it to be formatted that way. Is there any way around this, maybe like a substitute method or a quick efficient way to get rid of the 0 before I put it in Math.min parameter. I could do an if statement that checks then parses a `substring`, but that seems to tedious and inefficient. Any ideas?

Comment: How does your user input produce `0700` unless you're specifically parsing it to base 8?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is 08 not a valid integer literal in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7218760/why-is-08-not-a-valid-integer-literal-in-java) (0700 is valid, but it goes wrong for the same reason, nothing to do with `Math.min`)

Comment: 0700 is Octal integer man

Comment: Rather than substring you could take the user input and parse it, for example, `Integer.parseInt(input);`, will convert it to a valid integer `700`.

Comment: The whole point was to have the program read military time, but I didn't consider that military time and base 8 have a few things in common

Answer (score 0):

Call the following function on any of the inputs with leading 0s (given that they are strings), then convert the new string into an integer with `Integer.parseInt` and then proceed with your normal `Math.min` function on this final integer:

```
//This function takes in a string that is of the form of a integer with 
//leading zeros i.e. it would take in 0008000 and return the string 8000
public static String removeZeros(String str) {
    String regexpattern = "^0+(?!$)"; //regex pattern to find leading zeros
    str = str.replaceAll(regexpattern, ""); //remove leading zeros in string
    return str; //return string
}
```