# int with leading 0's behave strangely

Tags: java, int

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Integer with leading zeroes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/565634/integer-with-leading-zeroes)

Can someone please tell me what is going on here? When I initialize an int with leading zeroes the program does not ignore the zeroes and instead does some other operation I am unaware of.

```
int num = 0200;

System.out.println(num); // 128

System.out.println(033); // 27
```

Comment: @aaaa bbbb: Did you click the `close` link and *actually* vote to close?  Are you just just saying you think you should vote to close?

Comment: I'm not a registered user, so I don't get to actually close.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sure - it's treating it as an *octal* literal, as per the Java Language Specification, [section 3.10.1](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#3.10.1):

> An octal numeral consists of an ASCII digit 0 followed by one or more of the ASCII digits 0 through 7 and can represent a positive, zero, or negative integer.
>
> ```
> OctalNumeral:
>         0 OctalDigits
>
> OctalDigits:
>         OctalDigit
>         OctalDigit OctalDigits
>
> OctalDigit: one of
>         0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
> ```
>
> Note that octal numerals always consist of two or more digits; 0 is always considered to be a decimal numeral-not that it matters much in practice, for the numerals 0, 00, and 0x0 all represent exactly the same integer value.

Comment: Of course I don't know why I couldn't think of that. It gave an error when I put a 9 in there! Thanks for the fast reply, Jon!

Comment: Ok, im deleting my answer. The Java specification should be clear enough.

Answer (score 6):

That's an octal (base 8) literal.

Similarly, `0x27` is a hexadecimal (base 16) literal, with a decimal value of 39.