# Prevent Int from changing 012345 to 5349

Tags: java, formatting, int, typeconverter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Integer with leading zeroes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/565634/integer-with-leading-zeroes)

The program I am coding requires me to label an item with an inventory number of 012345 and store it in a int variable.

This is a stripped down example of what I am doing:

```
int test = 012345;
System.out.println(test);
```

this prints as:

```
5349
```

How do I get it to print out as 012345 rather than 5349?

EDIT: I am entering this into the parameter of a constructor for a custom class i am initializing. Then I use a method to return what the current number is, then print it to the terminal window.

Comment: `012345` literal makes Java sees your 10-supposed-base number as 8-base (octal) because of the 0 prefix.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You get a wrong number because when you prepend zero to an integer literal, Java interprets the number as an *octal*  (i.e. base-8) constant. If you want to add a leading zero, use

```
int test = 12345;
System.out.println("0"+test);
```

You can also use the [formated output functionality](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html) with the `%06d` specifier, like this:

```
System.out.format("%06d", num);
```

`6` means "use six digits"; '0' means "pad with zeros if necessary".

Comment: +1. *Very* unexpected behaviour. But it is not only Java that does this.

Comment: @Thilo afaik, almost all language interpret int with leading zero to be octal number.

Comment: @Thilo This behavior is borrowed from C. Octal was a popular base in the PDP-11, because their machine code used groups of three bits to indicate register numbers and other parts of the instruction.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight This works, Thanks! Not sure if it is what is expected though. 
I added some additional information to my question to clarify. Mind letting me know if there is another work around you can think of?

Thanks

Comment: @MattGrixti Take a look at an alternative that uses `format`.

Answer (score 0):

As already said, int value with leading zero is considered as octal value. If you don't need to have test as int, why not make it string? Like

```
String test= new String("012345");
```

And if you want to use int for test, you can do not prepend 0, rather just use the number and prepend 0 at the time of printing.

In case if you're wondering how will you find how many  leading zero are to be prepended, you may do like this

```
int lengthOfItemID=6;
int test=12345;
String test1=new String("000000"+test);
System.out.println(test1.substring(test1.length()-lengthOfItemID));
```

Pardon syntax mistakes, been years I last worked with java.

Comment: Please, make sure at least that the code compiles before posting it as an answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can get the right result by using `Integer.parseInt`.  That will make your string into a decimal string.  (found [here](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t129905-convert-numeric-string-into-integer-java.html)).  The JAVA API [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) states that it takes a string and returns a signed decimal.