# Bitwise operator unexpected behavior

Tags: java, bitwise-operators

Can someone explain this java bitwise operator behavior??

```
System.out.println(010 | 4); //  --> 12
System.out.println(10 | 4);  //  --> 14
```

Thank you!

Comment: 010 creates an octal literal.

Comment: This has nothing to do with bitwise operations, as your own examples demonstrate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first number is interpreted as octal. So `010 == 8`.

Starting from that, it is easy to see, that

```
8d | 4d == 1000b | 0100b == 1100b == 12d
```

The second number is interpreted to be decimal, which yields

```
10d | 4d == 1010b | 0100b == 1110b == 14d
```

*(Where `d` indicates a decimal number and `b` indicates a binary one.)*

Comment: Also it is related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/565634/integer-with-leading-zeroes ... but i didn't figure that were the reason till now. Thank you.