# Virtual Vending Machine

Tags: java

So far I have written this code for a virtual vending machine:

```
public class VirtualVender {
        public static void main(String[] args){
        int MILK_CHOCOLATE = 01;
        int DARK_CHOCOLATE = 02;
        int LIGHT_CHOCOLATE = 03;
        int COOKIE_CHOCOLATE = 04;
        int SELECTION;
        System.out.println("********************");
        System.out.println("Vending Machine");
        System.out.println("Enter Your Selection");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        SELECTION = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("********************");
    }
}
```

So from my understanding the user input should now be stored in SELECTION, but how do I get SELECTION to bring up MILK_CHOCOLATE if I inputted 01? if you need a more indepth question just respond and I'll try and explain my question better.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You compare them with an `if` or `switch`. Or you use a `Map` to do it for you. Also read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/565634/integer-with-leading-zeroes) for your `0` prefixed ints.

Comment: For what it's worth, if you want the user to actually enter in the leading zeroes, you'll have to compare strings, not numbers.

Comment: Java Virtual Vending Machine... JVVM

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of different ways to do it. Here's one:

```
if (SELECTION == MILK_CHOCOLATE) {
  System.out.println("Please enjoy your milk chocolate.");
}
```

By the way, the convention is to use `ALL_UPPERCASE` for constants, that is, values that will stay the same throughout the life of your program. So while `MILK_CHOCOLATE` is a constant, the user's selection isn't. You should name that variable `selection` instead. The Java compiler doesn't care, but the code will be easier for other programmers to read.

Comment: It's also good habit to start declaring things as `final` if you know ahead of time that the value should never change. Eg, `final int MILK_CHOCOLATE 01`

Answer (score 1):

Declare [an enum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) that defines your flavours and associated integer values:

```
public enum Flavour {
  MILK_CHOCOLATE(1), 
  DARK_CHOCOLATE(2), 
  LIGHT_CHOCOLATE(3), 
  COOKIE_CHOCOLATE(4);

  private final int value;

  private Flavour(int value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  public static Flavour fromValue(int value) {
    for (Flavour f : values()) {
      if (f.value == value) {
        return f;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  // Add a toString() method if you want to better control
  // how the flavour names are printed
}
```

Then use your enum to validate the user input values:

```
System.out.println("********************");
System.out.println("Vending Machine");
System.out.println("Enter Your Selection");

// Use try-with-resources to close Scanner:
try (Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in)) {
  int selection = input.nextInt();

  Flavour flavour = Flavour.fromValue(selection);

  if (flavour != null) {
    System.out.println(flavour);
  } else {
    System.out.println("Bad selection!");
  }
  System.out.println("********************");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use cases man.

```
String output; 
switch (selection) {
            case 1:  output = "milk chocolate";
                     break;
            case 2:  output = "dark chocolate";
                     break;
            ..

            default: output = "Not a correct value."
}
```

I believe they resemble the vending machine problem or circuits in general the best.