# Understanding bitwise operations and their application in Java

Tags: java, bitwise-operators, bit, bit-shift

I think understand what they fundamentally do - operate on bits (flip, shift, invert, etc...).

My issue is that I don't know when I'd ever need to use them, and I don't think I fully understand bits.

I know that there are 8 bits in a byte and I know that bits are either a `0` or `1`.  Now here is where I start to get confused... I believe data types define combinations of bits differently.  So if I declare an `int`, 32 bits are set aside for numbers, if I declare a char, 8 bits are set aside and the bits for that data type define a letter.

Running with that idea, I did the following basic operation in java which confuses me:

```
int num = 00000010;
System.out.println(num);
```

This prints `8` and if I define `num` this way:

```
int num = 00000100;
System.out.println(num);
```

This prints `64`

So to practice with bitwise operations (just for the hell of it) I tried this:

```
int num = 00000010 << 1;
System.out.println(num);
```

And it prints `16` where as I thought it would shift the bits by one to the left and print `64`.

What is happening here, and when would I ever need to apply this method of manipulating bits?

Comment: [The meaning of an `int` starting with a `0`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/565634/integer-with-leading-zeroes)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are accidentally specifying an *octal* literal when you specify a number with a leading zero.

```
00000010 => 1*8^1 + 0*8^0 => 8
00000100 => 1*8^2 + 0*8^1 + 0*8^0 => 64
```

The [JLS, Section 3.10.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1), describes octal and binary literals:

> An octal numeral consists of an ASCII digit 0 followed by one or more
>   of the ASCII digits 0 through 7 interspersed with underscores, and can
>   represent a positive, zero, or negative integer.
>
> A binary numeral consists of the leading ASCII characters 0b or 0B
>   followed by one or more of the ASCII digits 0 or 1 interspersed with
>   underscores, and can represent a positive, zero, or negative integer.

You are bit-shifting your `8` by one to the left, effectively multiplying it by `2` to get `16`.  In bits:

```
00000100 => 00001000
(8 => 16)
```

Binary literals are expressed with leading `0b`, e.g.:

```
0b000010 => 2
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, when would you ever need to do something like this?

Comment: Bit shift operators are equivalent to multiplying by `2^amount` for `<<` and dividing by `2^amount` for `>>`.

Comment: Are you aware of anyone ever deliberately using octal notation in Java who would have been bothered by needing a different prefix?  Java's borrowing of a leading zero as an octal prefix seems like an odd choice.