# Clarification about "int" number that begins with 0

Tags: java

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 012;
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Why the output is : `10`?

Comment: printing an octal number

Comment: Don't forget to chose a right answer

Comment: possible duplicate of [Integer with leading zeroes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/565634/integer-with-leading-zeroes)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If a number starts with 0 it's an octal number with base 8.
012 is in decimal a 10

Comment: @user2642221 You're welcome - if this answer solved your problem, please accept it as answer to your question (by clicking on the checkmark).

Answer (score 7):

See the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html):

> An octal numeral consists of an ASCII digit **0 followed by one or more
>   of the ASCII digits 0 through 7** interspersed with underscores, and can
>   represent a positive, zero, or negative integer.

It's a [good practice](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/underscores-literals.html) to write:

```
int i = 0_12;
```

It might be clearer now, `i` in decimal is 2*8<sup>0</sup> + 1*8<sup>1</sup> = 10.

Answer (score 3):

**Octal Number** :
Any number start with `0` is considered as an octal number (`012`) i.e.  base-8 number system

Simple octal number evaluation :

```
1*8^1 + 2*8^0 = 10
```

[Octal Number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal)

[For More information about Number System](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/computer_fundamentals/computer_number_system.htm)

Answer (score 2):

012 is the octal value for 10 in decimal. So your telling java to print the integer at octal pos 012. Here: http://www.asciitable.com/ shows octal to decimal vaulue conversions.