# long declared in class but constructor seems to wait for int

Tags: java

I have the following class in Java:

```
class Adresse4 {
    private String strasse;
    private String hausnummer;
    private int postleitzahl;
    private String ort;
    private long telefon;

    Adresse4(String strasse, String hausnummer, int postleitzahl, String ort, long telefon) {
        this.strasse = strasse;
        this.hausnummer = hausnummer;
        this.postleitzahl = postleitzahl;
        this.ort = ort;
        this.telefon = telefon;
    }
    Adresse4(Adresse4 ad) {
        this.strasse = ad.strasse;
        this.hausnummer = ad.hausnummer;
        this.postleitzahl = ad.postleitzahl;
        this.ort = ad.ort;
        this.telefon = ad.telefon;
    }
}
```

and creating an object from this class like this:

```
Adresse4 adTest = new Adresse4("Lothstraße", "22", 80999, Ort.Berlin, 09909999);
```

My IDE tells me that the integer number is too large where I have declared a long.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Integer with leading zeroes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/565634/integer-with-leading-zeroes)

Comment: Also, `long` literals must be suffixed with `L`.

Comment: already tried, didn't work.

Comment: Well, because `09909999` is too big for either `int` or `long`.

Comment: A phone number is better represented as a `String`, not a numeric value.

Comment: @Pillar, or one step further, a phone number might be best represented by a class; I dislike domain modeling using String objects.

Answer (score 1):

Numbers which start with a `0` are in octal. e.g. `012` is 10 in decimal.

The number `09` isn't valid because `9` is not an octal digit.

In short, phone numbers are not integers and they usually include formatting such as leading 0's or `+` for international.  You are better off storing it as a `String` or a `PhoneNumber` type which wraps a String.

e.g. my phone number starts `+44 75...` and the `+` would be discarded as an integer.