# Getting Java To Recognise The Early Morning Hours In An If Statement Range

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a method where the user inputs the hour (eg. 13:00 for 1pm) into the console (this is a console application) and depending on the hour of the day, my object would be a certain price. I've got Java to recognise the hours, but I'm having so much trouble with the early morning hours (00:00-04:59).

I've converted the time into an integer using substring and parseInt and the if statement below works well up until 23:59, if I type 01:00 or 03:30, nothing happens. Here's what I've done so far, I hope that you can help me. :)

```
int hrs = Integer.parseInt(hrsString);
int mHrs = 0;
if (hrs == 00)
  mHrs = 24;
if (hrs == 01)
  mHrs = 25
```

Etc. up to 04

```
if ((hrs >= 22) && (mHrs <= 28))
   price = 100.00
else if ((hrs >= 05) && (hrs <= 16))
   price = 20.00
```

Etc. up to 21.

Comment: Numbers starting with 0 are octals. Change `01` to `1` See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/565634/integer-with-leading-zeroes

Comment: You should be able to remove leading zeros using `substring`.

Comment: That's what I'm doing, I'm not using the minutes, I have a separate minString

Comment: Use the java 8 time API to deal with times as `LocalTime` instances (or jodatime in pre Java 8).

Comment: Aren't `1` and `01` the same value?

Comment: @noumenal if I've only got two characters can I use CharAt?

Comment: Sure, but you would have to treat the return value as a `char`: `hrs.charAt(0) == '0'`

Comment: And after that do Integer.parseInt? That's not my problem though.

Comment: `parseInt` expects a string, not a char. Read the Java Documentation. If you have to deal with a char, you need something like `String.valueOf(char)`. To avoid this back and forth casting, just use the substring: `hrsString.substring(0)`

Comment: if (hrsString.substring(0, 0) == 0) {
        hrsString = hrsString.substring(1); //Getting rid of a leading zero
    }

Comment: static int DAY = 6;
    static int EVENING = 16;
    static int NIGHT = 22;
    static double day_fare = 100.0;
    static double evening_fare = -99.0; //Not sure what you want here
    static double night_fare = 20.0;`

Comment: And then: 
    if (hrs >= DAY && < EVENING) {
     price = day_fare; 
    } else if (hrs >= EVENING && < NIGHT) {
     price = evening_fare;
    } else if (hrs >= NIGHT && < DAY) {
     price = night_fare;
    } else {
     System.out.println("Error");
    }

Comment: Using the built-in [`LocalTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) class would be much easier. It knows how to parse strings. It knows how to compare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem lies here:

```
if ((hrs >= 22) && (mHrs <= 28))
   price = 100.00
else if ((hrs >= 05) && (hrs <= 16))
   price = 20.00
```

Based on the code fragments you've provided, when it's `03:00` then `hrs` will be `3` and `mHrs` will be `27`. So it will *not* be the case that `(hrs >= 22) && (mHrs <= 28)`. This will never happen in the early hours of the morning.

I'm not sure what the point of `mHrs` is, but if it serves no other purpose than this line, I would suggest ditching the variable altogether and using this:

```
if ((hrs >= 22) || (hrs <= 4))
   price = 100.00
else if ((hrs >= 05) && (hrs <= 16))
   price = 20.00
```

Otherwise, if you need `mHrs` for other purposes, you could try this:

```
if ((hrs >= 22) || (mHrs >= 24 && mHrs <= 28))
   price = 100.00
else if ((hrs >= 05) && (hrs <= 16))
   price = 20.00
```