# Why Integers change their value when zeros are added to the left?

Tags: java, int

I just wanted to experiment with some integers and assigned the value "0013" to an integer a. When I print the value to the output console I get "11". What causes this? Why I do not get 13 ?

```
 int b = 0013;
 System.out.println(b);
```

Comment: diuplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/473282/how-can-i-pad-an-integers-with-zeros-on-the-left

Comment: it is not a duplicate , I ask "why" ..

Comment: @Teo you are correct.

Comment: Java has taken over many details from C and C++, including the leading `0` for octal (because digit 0 looks like letter o in octal, I guess) and `0x` for hexadecimal (0 in parallel to octal, x because it is in ‘hex’, I am still guessing). C was designed for low-level programming where particularly hexadecimal numbers were useful, I am not sure whether octal really were or they just thought they were or wanted to include them for completeness. Back in the very old days I have seen octal numbers used on a computer with 6 bit character set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A leading zero mean octal. Just like a leading 0x mean hexadecimal

Answer (score 1):

Java has <s>accidentally</s> automatically taken your number to be an octal number. Unlike hexadecimal notation, where the number is preceded by a `0x`, octal is proceeded by a single zero. The compiler has probably taken your number and made it into an octal format.

Try using `13` instead of `0013`

Comment: not accidently ...

Comment: Thanks! That explains everything!

Comment: Could I somehow tell the compiler to read the integer as a decimal number?

Comment: @Teo You probably shouldn't. Quote: _Just don't use the leading 0 if you don't mean octal. After all, they are not exactly useful(and programmers who do know about octal numbers will get confused when they see 09F)._ [Source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/565634/integer-with-leading-zeroes)