# Curve fitting through the Origin for Linear equation y = mx

Tags: curve-fitting, apache-commons-math

Is there a way to force Apache commons math to fit a linear curve of the form (`y = mx + 0`) through the origin (0,0).
So far I've used both PolynomialCurveFitter and SimpleCurveFitter, but none of them is returning a result that passes through the origin.
E.g:

```
final WeightedObservedPoints wopts = new WeightedObservedPoints();
//Add observed points to wopts: 
...
final PolynomialCurveFitter curveFitter = PolynomialCurveFitter.create(1);
double[] coeff = {0.0, 042};  //y = 0.042x + 0
curveFitter.withStartPoint(coeff);
final double[] bestPrediction = curveFitter.fit(wopts.toList());
```

but bestPrediction[0] is not 0.0
Any hint will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I suggest adding the tag apache-commons-math to this question.

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
  double[] coeff = {0.0, 042};
```

you use an [octal integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/565634/integer-with-leading-zeroes) `042` (i.e. `8*4 + 2`) which is internally converted to the double value `34.0`.

Define the line as:

```
  double[] coeff = {0.0, 0.42};
```