# Integer object leading zero changing the value

Tags: java

My apologies in advance as I assume this has already been answered, but I can't seem to find it anywhere.  I'm passing an Integer with a leading zero to a method and instead of resolving as the value passed like I expect (leading zero not an effect) the value is changing.  Here is my call and method:

```
assertEquals("1800", job.validateTime(1800, 0400));
```

I test the output:

```
public String validateTime(Integer startTime, Integer endTime) {
        System.out.println(endTime);
}
```

...and the output is 256 where I would expect it to be 400 or 0400.  Would someone please help me understand what is happening here?  Thank you in advance!

Comment: A literal integer with a leading 0 is an octal (base 8) number, not base 10. The spec: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1

Comment: Integers are numbers. Real numbers do not start with `0`; if you need prepended `0`s, you need to use a `String` object.

Comment: This does not compile. The method does not return a `String`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Integer with leading zeroes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/565634/integer-with-leading-zeroes)

Comment: That makes sense.  I was just wondering if there was a way to not treat this as base 8.  This will be user input so I need to account for a possible leading zero.  This info is helpful and I will be able to come up with a solution now.  Thanks all.