# What is the result of adding 070+010 in java?

Tags: java

I tried to add the following integers together. But I wondered after see the output of the program.

```
class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 070;
        int b = 010;
        System.out.println(a+b);
    }
}
```

**Output**
64
Then how It happened I expected 80(10+70)

Comment: Starting a literal integer with 0 indicates that you're typing it in base 8

Comment: 64 is correct. By prefixing your numbers with a zero you are telling Java that they are *octal* values instead of decimal ones.

Comment: @Michael Is there a canonical dupe target for octal typos? Seems it pops up often enough

Comment: @slim to be made aware that it doesn't compile?

Comment: @JonK Maybe this one? [Integer with leading zeroes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/565634/5221149)

Comment: @Andreas Good find. I've cleaned it up