# How does java handle Integers (consisting of 0s and 1s only) with many digits?

Tags: java, binary, integer

In the code below, the output to the console is 521.

There are exactly 32 digits in that input.

Can someone please explain or provide links that explain how the **number** variable has been converted to 521.

```
int number = 00000000000000000000000000001011;
System.out.println(number);
```

Comment: Numbers with a leading `0` are considered octal (i.e. base-8) in Java. Your usage of just 0 and 1 suggests you want to write a binary number, then you should prefix it with `0b` (i.e. `0b1011`).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are integer literals with leading zeroes interpreted strangely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/565634/why-are-integer-literals-with-leading-zeroes-interpreted-strangely)

Comment: It is octal number, not binary: `521 = 512 + 8 + 1 = 1 * 8^3 + 0 * 8^2 + 1 * 8^1 + 1 * 8^0`.